# Building PHP WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: php, wysiwyg, php-parser

I am building a web application in which the user may add a page, edit the layout, drag drop element, resize element, format the text, edit the element attribute etc.
In the page the user may include (retrieve) dynamic data, like maybe data from database, data generated by php code, etc. 

I have played around with cakephp and jquery lately and tried to build this app. But I stumbled upon on how to appropriately display the php code. I tried to look into the cakephp core code and find about output buffering and tried to utilize output buffering to parse the php code and use regex to display it but it is more likely to reinvent the wheel if I write the parser my self


What I am asking is:
Ok, to be more simple and specific I just want to ask, how to save and load the page that was created by the user especially if the page contains php code. I just want to know is there any other method than write my own parser or maybe a library to parse a php code?

Ok that's all for now, does anyone have any idea how to implement it? Or maybe any page / website that could be useful to take some reference from? Maybe a sample code from which I can take some reference
Thanks

Comment: You're asking several big questions here. Is this your first PHP project?

Comment: install drupal or joomla!, go on a website design course, read about 3 or 4 php and mysql books, join a number of forums and read, join you local PHP user group etc. etc.

Comment: Like fredley, I suspect you're over-stretching yourself. But you might want to have a look at http://pfp-studio.sourceforge.net/ and http://radria.sqlfusion.com/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you'll find any good answer here about that.

Whoa I don't know where to start. I'll start by the number 3. You want widgets. Then that means you have to create widget class or objects that possesses a template or something that makes them drawable "well, kinda". If I were you it would be loaded from javascript and not really from php. Each widget would be in some way individual applications loaded in a div using javascript.

Point 2, You wanted widgets. When you add widgets to your page, you have to save some informations, like Position, Title, dimensions and so on. You may even save creation parameters. For exemple a ListWidget may be started with different ItemProvider. That way you don't have to write 1000 widgets but only one that shows different content. That said you have widgets, dimension and position. Now that lead us to point 1.

Point 1. Once you have your widgets, position and dimensions, you send the data you used to create them associated with the page to the server. That lead us two point 2 again.

Once you have saved a page. You can see it by retrieving all widgets with parameters and so on. That leaves you 2 options.

1. Generate Javascript that will recreate the saved widgets.
2. Generate Html will all the widgets.

Option 1 is simpler since option 2 won't bind html to javascript by itself. Solution 2 on the other hand is better since there is only 1 request to the server.

Oh and a last thing, You should set yourself some limits. That kind of thing can get very complicated and unfortunately not that great. See drupal for example. It does lots of cool stuff but as soon as you install lots of module. Drupal transform itself in some sort of memory eating monster. And almost all the time you don't really need that much of dynamic content. Fixed layouts will do work nice almost 99% of the time.

I'm also forced to say that but if you try to create an application that give users as much power as a scientist that could raise a 7 legged cat. I think you're going to play with really obscure forces!